# Weird Problem with Sublime 3 + Python: cannot enter open bracket "(" except in comments

Tags: python, keyboard, sublimetext3, key-bindings

Yesterday I had to reinstall my Sublime installation on my Mac after I seemed to have upset it.
So today I reinstalled the packages I want (for python, C++, php, javascript, html, css). But it seems I did one package too much as now I cannot enter the opening bracket "(" within any python file -except in comment lines.

Does anyone have an idea or solution to this problem? Otherwise I have to reinstall it once more with even less packages...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be package that got into the way. After I deinstalled the last 5 the error was gone. Thanks.